# Storyboards in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios5, storyboard, xcode4.2

Apple has advertised over 200 new features for iOS 5, but it seems only a few are available to developers as of: October 13, 2011. I was wondering how to use the Storyboard feature that was displayed on their developer page: http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/

I couldn't find much documentation, so does anyone know how to find this feature and utilize it in Xcode 4.2 for iOS 5 SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new project in XCode you should see the option "Use Storyboard" which will add a storyboard for you when the project is created.

For an existing project you can create a new file and under the "User Interface" section there is Storyboard.